Replace letters inside words that start with and end with a specific letter not occurring anywhere else with the same amount of a specific character
I am using the following code to replace each non-initial and non-final letter with ! inside words starting and ending with a not containing a anywhere else in the words:
import re

txt = 'aba accca azzza wwwwa accca wwasdwaww abmasedmwa'

regex = re.sub(r'\ba([^a]+)a\b', r'!\1!', txt)
print(regex)

However, the output is
!b! !ccc! !zzz! wwwwa !ccc! wwasdwaww abmasedmwa

I'd like to get this output:
a!a a!!!a a!!!a wwwwa a!!!a wwasdwaww abmasedmwa


You can use
import re

txt = 'aba accca azzza wwwwa accca wwasdwaww abmasedmwa'
pattern = r'(?<=\ba)[^\Wa]+(?=a\b)'
print( re.sub(pattern, lambda x: '!' * len(x.group()), txt) )

Or, with a function like below:
import re

def replace_inner_letters(letter, text):
    return re.sub(
        fr'(?<=\b{letter})[^\W{letter}]+(?={letter}\b)',
        lambda x: '!' * len(x.group()), text
    )

text = 'aba accca azzza wwwwa accca wwasdwaww abmasedmwa'
letter = 'a'
print( replace_inner_letters(letter, text) )

See the Python demo #1 and Python demo #2.
Details

(?<=\ba) - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a at the start of a word
[^\Wa]+ - one or more word chars other than a
(?=a\b) - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a at the end of a word

Output:
a!a a!!!a a!!!a wwwwa a!!!a wwasdwaww abmasedmwa

The lambda x: '!' * len(x.group()) replacement replaces the match value with the same amount of ! chars.

Thank you so much for code and especially for the explanations!!
